# How to apply gradient transparency on an object in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I have created an object and set it's opacity to 30% however I want the object to get less opacity as it goes down
how can I apply gradient opacity?

Comment: I already asked and answered this: [How to create a gradient opacity mask in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/how-to-create-a-gradient-opacity-mask-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you have an object, that you want to mask - although your question is not really very clear. So, this is a guess. But anyway, this technique works on vector objects and raster objects in Illustrator.

I used this image as an example:

[image: Example image for masking]

1. Draw a rectangle with no stroke, over the object to be masked - I assume if it's a vector, then object itself should be grouped.
2. Use the Gradient Tool on the rectangle to apply a gradient that goes from 100% white to 100% black.

[image: Rectangle with Gradient applied]

3. When you make the mask, the white end of the gradient will be 100% opaque, and the black end will be 100% transparent.
4. Select both the object for masking, and the rectangle with the gradient.
5. Open the Transparency panel - if you cant already see it, click `Window` > `Transparency`. Hit the `Make Mask` button.

[image: Transparency Panel]

6. Then you can perhaps add a colour fill to a new rectangle and send it to the back, to use as a background. Then you will be able to see the transparency of your masked object over the background.

[image: Example of masked object over a solid background]

Answer (score 2):

Open the gradient panel in Illustrator.

You can find the colors which you have used for the gradient.

Then click one of the colors you have to reduce the opacity in the options below:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the gradient Panel]

If you cant find the gradient panel in the right side widget, please go to Window and click on Gradient for the panel to appear.

Comment: This only works if the object has a solid color fill.  A much better method is to use a gradient opacity mask

Comment: Yes I go with cai it is better you can check out this link https://youtu.be/QZ1LrDz4S_Q